# Does anyone know the name of this insect?

Tags: species-identification

Living in São Paulo, Brazil. Thanks for helping me.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No guarantuee due to the low photo quality, but the habitus of this specimen looks like a [weevil (Curculionoidea)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil) to me.
This beetle superfamily has characteristic elbowed (geniculate) antennae and prominent snouts. Their bodies are usually rather compact and robust.

If you still have the specimen, you could check, if you can recognize these characteristics (on the [right photo (Hectonichus CC-BY-SA-4.0)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Curculionidae_-_Polydrusus_impar.JPG) is a specimen of the similar-looking genus [*Polydrusus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydrusus) as comparison):

[image: Curculionoidea]